# Livestream video vs livestream

Tags: word-usage

Is writing "Livestream video" redundant as a livestream is always (?) a video? If so, should it be also be replaced with livestream?

Comment: Not redundant. A 'livestream' (or, often, a 'live stream') can be audio only. I listen to BBC radio that way on my phone and PC. "Listen to BBC World Service internet radio online. Access the free radio **live stream** and discover more radio stations at one glance."

Comment: You can also livestream a game, or livestream an event, so specifying *video* makes it more specific.

Comment: Whoever CVd as opinion based should reconsider.

Comment: Got it,  Thanks very much. You are welcome to convert your comments into an answer.

Comment: Someone voted to close this as an "opinion based" question.  I disagree-- you can objectively answer whether the word "Livestream" *always* refers to a video or not, and whether "video" is redundant.  Opinion does not come into the question.